# how to make a custom json rails routes and make the tests pass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Edit 2: OMG I AM SO STUPID.  In my spec I have a `let(:response) {MyModel.create()}` so thats why its failing.  Going to delete post
(edited for clarity)
In my routes file

```
root "search_email#index"
get  "search_email/retrieve_last_user_survey" => "search_email#retrieve_last_user_survey"
```

Controller

```
class SearchEmailController < ApplicationController
  def retrieve_last_user_survey
    render :json => "")
  end
end
```

Spec file

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe SearchEmailController, type: :controller do
  describe 'GET #retrieve_last_user_survey' do
    before do
      get :retrieve_last_user_survey, :params => { :email => 'abc@abc.com'}
    end

    it "returns http success" do
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
    end
  end
end
```

When try to run my test, i get this

```
Failure/Error: expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
expected a response object, but an instance of Relational::Response (custom model name) was received
```

I have no idea why I am not getting a response object, I know I am hitting the controller method cause I inserted `puts` and I can see it.

Also on a semi related note. If i create a button that hits this route. why does it redirect me to a `show` route. I thought it would just return some http request that i can see in the dev console. I know cause said I dont have a show route or a show template.

Comment: your routes suggest that you will post to retrieve_last_user_survey, but your test uses get

Comment: I was testing stuff out.  but it still doesnt work if I change it to get in routes.

Comment: nevermind.  found the error in my spec. i have a `let(:response) {Response.new()}` so the spec was picking that up instead

Comment: The test will pass anyway if the route is POST and the request is GET @LesNightingill, why? I don't know

Answer (score 0):

It's not meant to be facetious, but to get the test to pass, replace the render line in the controller with:

```rb
head :ok
```

Does the test pass? Probably. So now add some expectation on the content header, and then finally the content itself.

If you break it down into small pieces, you should find the problem. It's not obvious from what you've shared, we can't see into the controller method.

Comment: even if i put nothing in the controller method but `render json: ""`  or `head :ok`
 does not make it pass. still says `expected a response object, but an instance of Relational::Response was received`

Comment: nevermind.  found the error in my spec. i have a `let(:response) {Response.new()}` so the spec was picking that up instead